# What is the best way to send array buffer from React client to C# server?

Tags: javascript, c#, file, arraybuffer

I have an array buffer that created from pdf file, I have to send that data to the server side. What is the type C# may want to get? What type should I send from the client side? not sure what is the helpful way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it by:

The client side:

```js
    const formData = new FormData()
    formData.append('file', new Blob([fileData]))
    const options: any = {
      method: 'POST',
      body: formData
    }

    fetch(url,options).then(res=>...)
```

The server function:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UploadFile(IFormFile file)
{
    // process the uploaded file
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use content-type `multipart/form-data` on client side.

```
<form method="POST" action="/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="pdfFile">
  <input type="submit" value="Upload">
</form>
```

If you are using ajax then

```
var fileInput = $('form')[0];
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('file', fileInput.files[0]);

$.ajax({
  url: '/upload',
  type: 'POST',
  data: formData,
  processData: false,
  contentType: false,
  success: function(response) {
    console.log('File uploaded successfully');
  },
  error: function(error) {
    console.error('Error uploading file');
  }
});
```

If you are using axios then

```
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('file', file);
axios.post('/api/upload', formData, {
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
  }
}).then(response => {
  // Handle success
}).catch(error => {
  // Handle error
});
```

And use this code on ASP.NET.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UploadFile(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    // process the uploaded file
}
```

In React using ArrayBuffer, looks like this

```
import axios from 'axios';

const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('file', new Blob([arrayBuffer]));

axios.post('/api/upload', formData, {
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
  }
}).then((response) => {
  // Handle the response
}).catch((error) => {
  // Handle the error
});
```

Comment: First, thank for the quick answer. I have the data as `ArrayBuffer`, can I send like this here: `formData.append('file', file)`? what will be the content type and what should be the type in the serve side?

Comment: @ESI I'll update soon, and check it.
On server side, you can receive the formdata through `HttpPostFileBase` object.

Comment: What is `HttpPostFileBase` file type? I get an error that this type could not be found.

Comment: `System.Web.HttpPostedFileBase`